# Why does the app crash when i click the search button?

Tags: android

```
places = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
   places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
           if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
               destination = place.getAddress().toString();
               destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");
               Log.d("Welcome", destination);
               getDirection();
           }else
           {
               Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please ONLINE",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();
           }
       }


       @Override
       public void onError(Status status) {
        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this,""+status.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });

    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

    setUpLocation();




}

private void getDirection() {
    currentPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    @NonNull
    String requestApi = null;
    try {

        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
                "mode=driving&" +
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&" +
                "origin=" + currentPosition.latitude + "," + currentPosition.longitude + "&" +
                "destination" + destination + "&" +
                "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);


        Log.d("Welcome", requestApi);
        mService.getPath(requestApi).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                try {


                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                        String polyline = poly.getString("points");
                        polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);
                    }
                    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    for(LatLng latLng:polyLineList)
                        builder.include(latLng);
                    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                    CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,2);
                    mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);

                    polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                    polylineOptions.width(5);
                    polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                    polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                    polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                    polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                    greyPolyline= mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                    blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                    blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                    blackPolylineOptions.width(5);
                    blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                    blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                    blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                    blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size()-1))
                            .title("Pickup Location"));

                    //Animation
                    ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                    polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                    polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                    polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                            int percentValue = (int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                            int size = points.size();
                            int newPoints =(int)(size * (percentValue/100.0f));
                            List<LatLng> p=points.subList(0,newPoints);
                            blackPolyline.setPoints(p);

                        }
                    });
                    polyLineAnimator.start();

                    carMarker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                            .flat(true)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                    handler = new Handler();
                    index = -1;
                    next =1;
                    handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, " "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });




    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

the error log:

```
D/i-way: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?mode=driving&transit_routing_preference=less_driving&origin=37.4219983,-122.084&destinationDubai+-+United+Arab+Emirates&key=AIzaSyDk9oik-iVXrADcSniX-LE2PRX7FAeTEV0
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 144867953
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3ba91c0: ver 1 0
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.asliborneo.dev.iwaybiz, PID: 2444
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at app.asliborneo.dev.iwaybiz.Welcome$4.onResponse(Welcome.java:292)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 5BB6F27300EA-0001-098C-D8EF44217386
```

Comment: Hello,

Please check error message,
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference. I think you need to check is any value is null or not while parsing.

Comment: Have you debugged your code. Are you getting data for jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes"). Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query response, "routes" is coming as null that's why you are getting null jsonArray and your jsonArray.length function is failing.

Please check your URL, looks like destination is not correctly provided. It should be destination**=**Dubai

Answer (score 0):

It seems that route data is null for the selected path or transport. Try with below code.

```
if(jsonArray != null){
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
        String polyline = poly.getString("points");
        polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);
    }
}else {
    // Route not found
}
```